# Facebook “Like” button's comment box sizing

Tags: facebook-like

When the user clicks the like button a comment box pops up that has a width of 450px.  This is too large for the space I have available.  As far as I can tell, this comment box does not seem to respond to the "data-width" property I had set here:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="290"  data-show-faces="false">
```

...so I had been forcing it with my css to this size:

```
iframe.fb_ltr { max-width:290px !important;}
```

All was good until it seems something just changed and this is no longer viable because the width of 450px is now being set within the iframe with this new? class:

```
<div class="fbpf pluginLikeFlyout pluginLikeFlyoutFull pluginLikeFlyoutFullButton">

.pluginLikeFlyoutFull {
    top: 24px;
    width: 450px;
}
```

Bottom line, is there another way to set the width of the comment box so it doesn't default to 450px?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: I ended up just updating the outer containers to overflow, and the users potentially have to scroll to see the full overlay...oh well.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my css:

```
div.fb-like.fb_iframe_widget > span {
 width: 100% !important;
}

div.fb-like.fb_iframe_widget{
 width: 100%;
}
```